# Dhcp Broadcast Through Switches

Tags: vlan, dhcp, layer2, trunk, broadcast

Think of a pc connected to switch1. Sw1 is connected to sw2(trunk port on both switches) and sw2 is connected to a router(dhcp server). Pc sends a dhcp broadcast. Does sw1 passes the broadcast through the trunk port(connected to sw2), without looking  at the mac table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, DHCP broadcast on Ethernet are sent to address FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF.

The 802.1AD document that define bridges (I.E. switches) operations state that (emphasis mine):

> The broadcast address and other group MAC Addresses apply to the use
>   of the MAC Service provided by a Bridged Local Area Network as a
>   whole. In the absence of explicit filters configured via management as
>   Static Filtering Entries, or via GMRP as Group Registration Entries
>   (Clause 14, Clause 10, 7.9), **frames with such destination addresses
>   are relayed throughout the network**

So by definition a broadcast is sent to all connected switches and host in the (V)LAN.

There's no MAC table lookup, since it is not needed.

Comment: So a trunk port is enough to send the broadcast to the other switch right?

Comment: It depends. You can restrict which VLAN are allowed to pass through a trunk port. A broadcast is propagated throughout the whole VLAN. So if the VLAN is allowed in the trunk, yes.